# Start MPlayer from a PHP command

Tags: php, bash, ubuntu, sh, libgphoto2

I am working on a project to create a photo booth. I have a camera (canon 550d) and a touchscreen pc (running ubuntu) which shows a webpage I wrote.

I am using [gphoto2](http://gphoto.sourceforge.net/) to control my DSLR from within the webpage using `exec()`, I can take photos easily.

My problem is that I want to also show a live preview from the camera before people take the photo. Now, I have a script ready which opens an MPlayer instance within a borderless window which also stays on top of everything, the code is in a file called `live.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
gphoto2 --capture-movie --stdout > fifo.mjpg & mplayer -cache 32 -demuxer 35 -noborder -geometry 50%:100 -ontop 1 fifo.mjpg
```

basically gphoto2 streams to fifo.mjpg and then MPlayer plays that file.

It all works fine and well when I run this from the terminal:

```
bash live.sh
```

It doesn't work if I run the same command from within php

```
exec("bash live.sh", $output);
```

Take a look at the outputs I get when running from these 2 environments

**Running from terminal (THIS WORKS)** :

```
MPlayer 1.2.1 (Debian), built with gcc-5.3.1 (C) 2000-2016 MPlayer Team
mplayer: could not connect to socket
mplayer: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.

Playing 1.
File not found: '1'
Failed to open 1.


Playing fifo.mjpg.


libavformat version 56.40.101 (external)
Capturing preview frames as movie to 'stdout'. Press Ctrl-C to abort.

*** Error ***             
An error occurred in the io-library ('Could not claim the USB device'):    Could not claim interface 0 (Device or resource busy). Make sure no other program (gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor) or kernel module (such as sdc2xx, stv680, spca50x) is using the device and you have read/write access to the device.
ERROR: Movie capture error... Exiting.
Movie capture finished (0 frames)
libavformat file format detected.
Cannot seek backward in linear streams!
Seek failed
[mjpeg @ 0x7f9cffecb540]Found EOI before any SOF, ignoring
[mjpeg @ 0x7f9cffecb540]Changeing bps to 8
[lavf] stream 0: video (mjpeg), -vid 0
VIDEO:  [MJPG]  1056x704  0bpp  25.000 fps    0.0 kbps ( 0.0 kbyte/s)
Load subtitles in ./
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_va_gl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[vdpau] Error when calling vdp_device_create_x11: 1
==========================================================================
Opening video decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg's libavcodec codec family
libavcodec version 56.60.100 (external)
Selected video codec: [ffmjpeg] vfm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg MJPEG)
==========================================================================
Audio: no sound
Starting playback...
[mjpeg @ 0x7f9cffecb540]Found EOI before any SOF, ignoring
[mjpeg @ 0x7f9cffecb540]Changeing bps to 8
Could not find matching colorspace - retrying with -vf scale...
Opening video filter: [scale]
Movie-Aspect is undefined - no prescaling applied.
[swscaler @ 0x7f9d00c36fa0]bicubic scaler, from yuv422p to yuyv422 using     MMXEXT
[swscaler @ 0x7f9d00c36fa0]using unscaled yuv422p -> yuyv422 special converter
VO: [xv] 1056x704 => 1056x704 Packed YUY2
Movie-Aspect is undefined - no prescaling applied.
VO: [xv] 1056x704 => 1056x704 Packed YUY2
V:   0.5   0/  0 37% 14%  0.0% 0 0 50%

MPlayer interrupted by signal 2 in module: enable_cache



MPlayer interrupted by signal 2 in module: video_read_frame
[mjpeg @ 0x7f9cffecb540]overread 8
[mjpeg @ 0x7f9cffecb540]EOI missing, emulating
V:   0.6   0/  0 36% 13%  0.0% 0 0 50%

Exiting... (Quit)
```

Despite all the errors, everything works surprisingly well.

**This is the output I get when running from an exec() in PHP (THIS DOES NOT WORK):**

```
array(16) {
  [0]=>
    string(71) "MPlayer 1.2.1 (Debian), built with gcc-5.3.1 (C) 2000-2016 MPlayer Team"
  [1]=>
    string(39) "Terminal type `unknown' is not defined."
  [2]=>
    string(0) ""
  [3]=>
    string(10) "Playing 1."
  [4]=>
    string(0) ""
  [5]=>
    string(0) ""
  [6]=>
    string(18) "Playing fifo.mjpg."
  [7]=>
    string(29) "
  Cache fill:  0.00% (0 bytes)"
  [8]=>
    string(0) ""
  [9]=>
    string(40) "libavformat version 56.40.101 (external)"
  [10]=>
    string(33) "libavformat file format detected."
  [11]=>
    string(39) "Cannot seek backward in linear streams!"
  [12]=>
    string(42) "[mjpeg @ 0x7fb771bec540]Changeing bps to 8"
  [13]=>
    string(38) "[lavf] stream 0: video (mjpeg), -vid 0"
  [14]=>
    string(69) "VIDEO:  [MJPG]  1056x704  0bpp  25.000 fps    0.0 kbps ( 0.0 kbyte/s)"
  [15]=>
    string(20) "Load subtitles in ./"
}
```

If anyone has any ideas on how to make this work, I will be very grateful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `exec` with `popen` and also background the script call.

```
pclose(popen("bash live.sh > /dev/null &", 'r'));
```

This way the code is executed in a shell detached from php. This might help MPlayer work.

Comment: I just tried running this from terminal:
php -r 'pclose(popen("bash live.sh > /var/www/html/booth/log.txt &", "r"));'

and it also works.

Comment: Does it work or does it NOT work ? Try adding the full path to the bash script call `/usr/bin/bash /path/to/live.sh`

Comment: no, it still does NOT work, not even your last suggestion.